# Data binding of an fx:object in flex for image and icon

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

Hi guys i'm learning flex, i had a flex app and it is populated using fx objects, the data is stored in these objects which are in a list, when i select a object its set to push to the next view where there is databinding bringing the hidden data from the object (as that object on the list page only shows the lable name, not the other attributes and values).

all that is working fine for anythng text related but i am trying to insert an embedded image into the object and for it to be pulled via databinding on the next page.

i have been following Ibrent tutorials on youtube which showed me eveything so far.

below is the data binding working for the opening hours bu i dont know what code to put in for an image or icon data binding on the next view.

```
    <fx:Object openingHours=" 2300 - 0400" icon="@Embed('assets/test.png')"/>
```

this is the next view where the databiding takes place.

Thanks guys :) Great resource for learning!

```
<s:Label id="openingHours" x="205" y="185" fontSize="20" text="{data.openingHours}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your object to:

> <fx:Object openingHours=" 2300 - 0400" id="hoursObj" src="@Embed('assets/test.png')"/>

and display it using something akin to:

> <s:BitmapImage source="{hoursObj.src}" />

Here is a link that shows the process using a custom renderer:

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/09/29/displaying-images-in-a-spark-list-control-using-a-custom-item-renderer-in-flex-4/

Not seeing the rest of your process I can't give you the exact answer but this should get you closer.